# Formatting cells in a table, without repeating the same code hundreds of times?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a display page for a lot of data.  some of the data is a short string, some of it is a long string(>200char) and some is numbers.   My issue is this:   When i create a a table and set its style, how do i make it so the style of the table sets a fixed size for the cells in that table, without manually setting it for each individual cell, becuase i have over 50 tables with 10 rows or more and each one has multiple cells. 
I am asking this because the data I am entering seems to be resizing the cells to make it fit, and it crushes the adjacent cells, which cant happen.
Here is a sample of what i want:

```
                             <table style={table_style_sub}>
                                <tr>
                                   <td><b>Client Name:</b></td>
                                    <td>{client2}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Location:</b></td>
                                    <td>{client2Location}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Phone:</b></td>
                                    <td>{client2Phone}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Emails:</b></td>
                                    <td>{client2Email}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style={cell_format}><b>Details:</b></td>
                                    <td>{client2Service}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

this is my table for example.   Here is the formatting:

```
var table_style_sub={
    margin: 'auto',
    width: '400px',
    marginBottom: '15px',
    border: '1px dotted black'
}
```

is there any way to add to this `table_style_sub` to make every `<td>` of the appropriate table have a width of `'Xpx'` without manually doing typing `<td style={{width:"Xpx}}>` over 300 times.

Here is the whole code if you want to see it to get an idea of how many lines i actually have: http://pastebin.com/6rzRz2Vj

Comment: is it possible for you to use jquery?

Comment: i am not familiar with jquery.  i could try.

Comment: Oh no, your code is so sad :( You just shouldn't repeat anything at all. Use `.map()`... Iterate through a data and map it to the view... This file is huge.

Comment: Honestly I don't even know where to begin. But if you're using react why wouldn't you just make a component that wraps up the tables rows and/or cells? You might also want to consider seeing a temp variable, or using ES6 destructuring assigns, or pretty much anything, to avoid this nightmare code :(

Comment: And why not just use CSS?!

Comment: @DaveNewton, i am not sure what you mean by 'And why not just use CSS?!'.  I am asking HOW to use css to do that.

Comment: You don't need to style every table cell in the cell itself-that's one of the points of having external stylesheets. Create a rule for cells in your css and you're largely done, there only thing you may need is a className on the relevant cells. You can abstract out a single row into a component. And all that object destructuring you can do with ES6, or at least pull out the array access into a temp variable. The code USD painful to read as-is and *really* needs refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in javascript itself,

In your code there seems to be a div with an id="messagesDiv" enclosing the table so could use that id and fetch the tds and then set their style to width in the javascript as shown below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="index-form" name="LoginForm">
<div class="card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--white-600" id="messagesDiv">
             
                        <h3>Contact Information</h3>
                        <table style={table_style}>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Legal Name: </b></td>
                                <td>{legalEntity}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Operating Name:</b> </td>
                                <td>{operatingName}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Role: </b></td>
                                <td>{string_role[role]}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Address 1: </b></td>
                                <td>{address1}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Address 2: </b></td>
                                <td>{address2}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>City:</b> </td>
                                <td>{city}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Province:</b></td>
                                <td>{province}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Country: </b></td>
                                <td>{country}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Postal Code:</b></td>
                                <td>{postalCode}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Phone:</b></td>
                                <td>{phone}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Fax:</b></td>
                                <td>{fax}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Email:</b></td>
                                <td>{email}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Admin Contact:</b></td>
                                <td>{adminContact}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Techncal Contact:</b></td>
                                <td>{technicalContact}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
</form>
<script>
 var div=document.getElementById("messagesDiv");
 var tds=div.getElementsByTagName("td");
 for(var i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
  tds[i].style.width='200px';
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, don't do it. You're writing in React. React is the opposite of such an approach.

Comment: @KrzysztofDąbrowski, haha yeah, i realized this afterwards that this would not work.